# Ansible-playbook how to add ssh_extra_vars parameter -vvv

Tags: ansible

is there a simple way to add the *very verbose* parameter '-vvv' to ssh if it is used  by ansible-playbook.

I try to call:

```
ansible-playbook -vvvv --ssh-extra-args '-vvv' --inventory ${INVENTORYFILE} --vault-password-file ${VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE} ansible/playbook-program-installation.yaml --extra-vars "target=$HOST_TARGET" "$@"
```

But the result is:

```
usage: ansible-playbook [-h] [--version] [-v] [--private-key PRIVATE_KEY_FILE]
                        [-u REMOTE_USER] [-c CONNECTION] [-T TIMEOUT]
                        [--ssh-common-args SSH_COMMON_ARGS]
                        [--sftp-extra-args SFTP_EXTRA_ARGS]
                        [--scp-extra-args SCP_EXTRA_ARGS]
                        [--ssh-extra-args SSH_EXTRA_ARGS]
[...]

ansible-playbook: error: argument --ssh-extra-args: expected one argument

[...]
```

How can I force ansible-playbook to accept the parameter '-vvv' for ssh so I got Information why ssh connection fails?

Comment: => `--ssh-extra-args='-vvv'`